# Reset a codefirst generated database on app_start

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a codefirst project using EF6 that I would like to reset the database each time the application starts (only in dev)

Is there a way to apply the initial migration followed by the update-database command without needing to do it from the PM window in VS?

I want to remove all data I generate while playing with the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the following in your Global.asax:

```
Database.Delete();
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
```

ApplicationDbContext would refer to the context you are trying to delete/migrate.

You might want to put a #if DEBUG or some other conditional so it doesn't make it to prod, though.

Comment: Thanks Dismissile, I do get an error on Database.Delete - Cannot drop database because it it currently in use.

Comment: You probably have sql management studio open and connected to the database. close it down and you should be good to go.
If it's hosted in IIS you could also stop the application for a second.

Comment: Only using VS to connect via the server explorer. Disconnecting from there doesnt help. If I close Vs and rerun the command again it works but seems pretty bad if I have to close VS everytime :(

Comment: @DiverDan Are you disposing of your contexts every time? If you don't do that, you could still have an active connection to the database.